# How to change UICollection View cell data with new data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to change UICollection View cell data with new data when user tap a button
I mean I want to remove previous data and add new one
I use `collectionView.reloadData()` but it adds new data to previous, not replace it.
How can I do that?

Comment: Could you add some code about how you populate `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be adding the new data to the existing data source.So the new data is added to the existing one. Better to add the code for this in the question.

Comment: The problem might be the logic behind the reload. Can you share the code snippet ,if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Before call `reloadData` you have to clean the list that you use to populate the collection.

The list is the one that you use in the method:

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`